# ColdFusion ValueList from SQL

Tags: jquery, sql, coldfusion

I'm trying to create a value list in ColdFusion. Basically, I want the users to be able to enter their fellow band members into individual fields. Then when submitted, any value which is present is stored into my database as a string rather than individual text values. When retrieving it from the database, run through it and use the comma as a separator and individually split the values again. On paper and in my head it sounds simple but I can't get my head round it. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Could please provide samples/specifics of what will be input by the user and how you want that input stored in the database?

Comment: I don't really know how to respond to that because i haven't actually created it yet, i want to use input fields, i've already come up with a method to increase/decrease the amount of fields in the form i just now need to make it so that those fields values are converted into a string using commas as separators eg. "John" "Luke" "Bob" becomes "John, Luke, Bob" and that is stored within the database, then when called up again on the site i want to run code which splits up "John ,Luke, Bob" back into "John" "Luke" "Bob". If your still with me here haha very confusing.

Comment: If you want to store "John,Luke,Bob" as an individual value you should give it more thought.  Your data will be a lot more difficult to work with that way.

Comment: It's the only way i could do it really, it's not viable creating excess fields based on the assumption that one band could have eight members as opposed to one being a duet. I'd rather store the values into a string which means i only ever have one database entry, i know there is a way of getting through the list of words and picking out each individual one, it's just a matter of making it happen.

Comment: Check out the jQuery from serialize function.  That may be the easiest (probably not the cleanest) way to get the values off of the page and into one string.

Comment: You would not create extra columns (ie fields). The data would be stored in rows, with the band id as a FK. So a band could have as many or as few members as needed. Databases were optimized to work with rows (or sets of data) - not lists. If you anticipate doing anything beyond a simple `select` (searching, deleting, updating), you are almost certainly better off *not* storing lists. Querying lists is awkward and error prone. Not to mention slower because anything beyond a simple select requires convoluted sql. I would *strongly* recommend you reconsider that design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to go with that solution you could simply use `listToArray`+`cfloop` or just `cfloop` to get the individual names:

```
<CFSET list_names = "John ,Luke, Bob" /> <!--- this should be the value from your db field --->
<CFSET array_names = listtoarray(list_names) />

<CFLOOP array="#array_names#" index="name">
    #name# is in the band<br />
</CFLOOP>
```

OR directly use the list and loop over it:

```
<CFSET list_names = "John ,Luke, Bob" /> <!--- this should be the value from your db field --->

<CFLOOP list="#list_names#" index="name">
    #name# is in the band<br />
</CFLOOP>
```

But ... I would save the band member names in a separate table - such as:

Table `bands`:

```
| id | bandname  |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | The Hives |
```

Table `bands_members`:

```
| band_id | name                   |
+---------+------------------------+
|   1     | Howlin’ Pelle Almqvist |
|   1     | Nicholaus Arson        |
|   1     | Vigilante Carlstroem   |
```

Comment: Yes I agree, your band members should be separate from a table containing the bands. You then "join" them in SQL on the common ID. I would avoid storing band members as a string in a column within the bands table. Better to have this "one to many" relationship for future purposes too.

Comment: i see where you are coming from, have an actual separate table for band members where the unique band id links the correct band members so say if 8 members are in a band they would have that band id in their field on this separate table. Im with you now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

With apologies for touting my own (free and open source) wares, DataMgr has something that might be particularly attractive for this situation.

You can pass in a comma-delimited list and it will save the list appropriately as rows in a related table.

So, you could have a "bands" table, a "players" table, a "band2players" table that joins them. If so, you could have a checkbox of available players (called, say "players).

Then when you submit your band, you could have a band_id started in Form.id (for example) and do the following:

```
 <cfset Application.DataMgr.SaveRelationList("band2players","band_id",Form.id,"player_id",Form.players)>
```

http://www.bryantwebconsulting.com/docs/datamgr/save-many-to-many-relationships.cfm

With a little extra work, you could even set up a "relation field" in DataMgr to make DataMgr act like the "bands" table has a "players" field, even though it would really just access the "bands2players" data in the background. This would allow you to save and retrieve using a comma-delimited list. You could even use names instead of ids if you wanted a textarea instead of a checkbox list.

http://www.bryantwebconsulting.com/docs/datamgr/lists.cfm